# Scrape Hotel data, assign tag to hotel, but sometimes different

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to scrape some data from Bookings.com (sorry i am a beginner). My goal is to extract the name of the hotel and how many rooms are available.

The hotel name is in the following HTML tag:

```
<span class="sr-hotel__name
" data-et-click=" ">Hotel New York</span>
```

I am getting the name of the hotels with the following code and print it to the console:

```
titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('sr-hotel__name')
for title in titles_element:
    # get the number of elements
    print('Hotel: ' + title.text)
```

This is properly working but there are two different tags for the rooms available which i identified:

```
<span class="only_x_left sr_rooms_left_wrap " data-x-left-count="6">
Nur noch 6 Zimmer auf unserer Seite verfügbar!
</span>
```

and

```
<span class="only_x_left sr_rooms_left_wrap js--highdemand-scarce" data-x-left-count="6">
Sehr gefragt – nur noch 6 auf unserer Seite verfügbar!
</span>
```

The problem is also, that sometimes this tag is not available because Booking.com doesnt provide the room availability. In this case i just want to print "No information".

### My goal is to assign the right room availability to the hotel and print it to the console, for example:

Hotel: Hotel New York

Rooms Available: 3

Hotel: Hilton Avenue

Rooms Available: No information

### and so on

How can i do this? I assume that i have to use a loop, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Here is the solution that I would use.

```
# get the hotels
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sr_item")
# now iterate through all hotels
for hotel in hotels:
    # get hotel name
    name = hotel.find_element_by_class_name('sr-hotel__name').text
    rooms = hotel.find_elements_by_class_name('sr_rooms_left_wrap')
    if (len(rooms)>0):
        room = rooms[0].get_attribute('data-x-left-count')
    else:
        room = "No information"
    print("Hotel : " + name)
    print("Rooms Available : " + room)
```